# code runninng in google chrome slowly

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Hi i am trying to make a Google+ style picture album. I am quite successful. But the weird fact is that the code runs slowly in Chrome, but works very well in Firefox. In Chrome, pictures load quite slowly and the rotation of album images(jquery part) is slow. Here is my code...

```
<?php
 $number_of_image_per_album=array(); 
 $query="SELECT album_id,album_name from albums WHERE user_id='18'";//user id
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 $num_of_album=mysql_num_rows($result);
 for($i=1,$k=0;$k<=800,$i<=$num_of_album;$k=$k+300,$i++)
   {
$array=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$album_id=$array['album_id'];
$album_name=$array['album_name'];
$query2="SELECT image_id,ext from images WHERE album_id='$album_id'";
$result2=mysql_query($query2);
$num_of_images=mysql_num_rows($result2);
$num_of_image_per_album[]=$num_of_images;
echo "<div class='image_stack' style='margin-left:",$k,"px'>";//create a album of images
$left=108;
$top=8;
for($j=1;$j<=$num_of_images;$j++)
{
    $array2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $image_id=$array2['image_id'];
    $image_ext=$array2['ext'];
    $image_name=$array2['image_name'];
    //$str="<img id='photo.$j' class='stackphotos' src='uploads/.$album_id./.$image_id.$image_ext' />";

    echo "<img id='photo$j' class='stackphotos' style='left: $left; top:$top ;' src='uploads/$album_id/$image_id.$image_ext' />";   

    $left=108-4;
    $top=8-2;
}   
 echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Here is my jquery part...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.image_stack').delegate('img', 'mouseenter', function() {//when user hover mouse on image with div id=stackphotos
        //if ($(this).hasClass('stackphotos')) {//
        // the class stackphotos is not really defined in css , it is only assigned to each images in the photo stack to trigger the mouseover effect on  these photos only
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var index=parent.index()-1;
        var num_of_image_per_album=<?php echo json_encode($num_of_image_per_album);?>;
        var num_of_image_for_specific_album=num_of_image_per_album[index];
      //  alert( num_of_image_for_specific_album);
        var i=0;
        var degree=0;
        for(i=1;i<=num_of_image_for_specific_album;i++)
        {

            parent.find('img#photo'+i).css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
            parent.find('img#photo'+i).css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
             degree=degree+10

            }

})
.delegate('img', 'mouseleave', function() {// when user removes cursor from the image stack
var parent = $(this).parent();
var index=parent.index()-1;
var num_of_image_per_album=<?php echo json_encode($num_of_image_per_album);?>;
var num_of_image_for_specific_album=num_of_image_per_album[index];

 for(i=1;i<=num_of_image_for_specific_album;i++)
    {

     parent.find('img#photo'+i).css( {'-webkit-transform':''});
        parent.find('img#photo'+i).css({ '-moz-transform': ''});


        }


});;
});
</script>
```

I am using 16.0.912.77 version of Crome.This also slow in safari.what is the problem.please advise me.Thank in advance.......

Comment: It has to be something in the Jquery/Javascript part. All the PHP code is run server side.

Comment: one thing that could speed it up is not to do `parent.find('img#photo'+i)` multiple times in a loop.  Also, you can combine `css` changes into a single call.

Comment: Oh..it also works well in opera.whats the problem with crome??

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out chrome's super cool profiler?

```
Right click page -> Inspect Element (or F12)
 -> Profiles 
 -> collect JavaScript CPU Profile
 -> Start
 -> Stop
 -> Read
 -> Fix Problems
 -> Repeat
```